# My code is showing error

Tags: java, algorithm

I want to implement the following algorithm :

1. If there are less than `Config.MAX_ACTION` sticks remaining 
     then the chooser must pick the minimum number of sticks (`Config.MIN_ACTION`).
2. For `Config.MAX_ACTION` or more sticks remaining then pick based on the 
     `actionRanking` parameter.
3. The `actionRanking` array has one element for each possible action. The `0`
     index corresponds to `Config.MIN_ACTION` and the highest index corresponds
     to `Config.MAX_ACTION`.
4. For example, if `Config.MIN_ACTION` is `1` and `Config.MAX_ACTION` is `3`, an 
       action can be to pick up 1, 2 or 3 sticks.
5. `actionRanking[0]` corresponds to `1`, `actionRanking[1]` corresponds to `2`, etc. The higher the element for an action in comparison to other elements, the more likely the action should be chosen.
6. First calculate the total number of possibilities by summing all the element values. Then choose a particular action based on the relative frequency of the various rankings.
7. For example, if `Config.MIN_ACTION` is `1` and `Config.MAX_ACTION` is 3: If the action rankings are `{9,90,1}` the total is `100`. Since `actionRanking[0]` is `9`, then an action of picking up 1 should be chosen about 9/100 times. 2 should be chosen about 90/100 times and 1 should be chosen about 1/100 times.
8. Use `Config.RNG.nextInt(?)` method to generate appropriate random numbers.
9. `sticksRemaining` means The number of sticks remaining to be picked up.
10. `actionRanking`: The counts of each action to take. The `0` index corresponds to `Config.MIN_ACTION` and the highest index corresponds to `Config.MAX_ACTION`.
11. return The number of sticks to pick up. `0` is returned for the following conditions: `actionRanking` is `null`, `actionRanking` has a length of `0`, or `sticksRemaining` is `<= 0`.

I have written the code as follows :

```
static int aiChooseAction(int sticksRemaining, int[] actionRanking) {
        if(actionRanking == null || actionRanking.length == 0 || sticksRemaining <= 0)
            return 0 ;
        else if(sticksRemaining < Config.MAX_ACTION)
            return Config.MIN_ACTION; //TODO change to appropriate value
        else
        {
            int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            int index = 0 ; 
            for(int i = 0; i < actionRanking.length; i++) {
                  if(actionRanking[i] >= max) {
                     max = actionRanking[i];
                     index = i ; 
                  }
            }
            if(sticksRemaining<max)
                return index+1;
            else
                return  Config.RNG.nextInt(Config.MAX_ACTION)+Config.MIN_ACTION;
        }
    }
```

The code for testing this function is as follows :

```
private static void testAiChooseAction() {
        boolean error = false;

        // 1.
        int action = Sticks.aiChooseAction(0, null);
        if (action != 0) {
            error = true;
            System.out.println("testAiChooseAction 1: for 0 sticks or null " 
                    + "actionRanking, response should be 0.");
        }

        // 2.
        int[] actionRanking = new int[] { 1, 100, 0 };
        action = Sticks.aiChooseAction(-5, actionRanking);
        if (action != 0) {
            error = true;
            System.out.println("testAiChooseAction 2: for negative sticks," 
                    + " response should be 0.");
        }

        // 3.
        action = Sticks.aiChooseAction(10, actionRanking);
        if (action < Config.MIN_ACTION || action > Config.MAX_ACTION) {
            error = true;
            System.out.println("testAiChooseAction 3: invalid action " 
                    + action);
        }

        // 4.
        // create and initialize to 0 an action ranking array
        actionRanking = new int[NUM_ACTIONS];

        // set the highest index to the highest ranking
        // so we expect the MAX_ACTION to be chosen
        actionRanking[actionRanking.length - 1] = 100;

        action = Sticks.aiChooseAction(10, actionRanking);

        if (action != Config.MAX_ACTION) {
            error = true;
            System.out.println("testAiChooseAction 4: expected " 
                    + Config.MAX_ACTION + " rather than " + action);
        }

        // 5.
        actionRanking = new int[] { 1, 6, 3 }; // test for 3 actions
        int[] responses = new int[actionRanking.length];

        // set seed to get repeatable "random" values
        Config.RNG.setSeed(123); 

        // call a bunch of times so there is reasonable chance of seeing the
        // expected distribution.
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            action = Sticks.aiChooseAction(10, actionRanking);
            responses[action - Config.MIN_ACTION]++;
        }
        if (responses[0] != 1037 || responses[1] != 5819 
                || responses[2] != 3144) {
            error = true;
            System.out.println("testAiChooseAction 5: for seed 123 "
                    + "responses were expected to be [1037, 5819, 3144] " 
                    + " but found " + Arrays.toString(responses));

        }

        // can you think of other tests that would be useful?
        // if so, then you can add them.

        if (error) {
            System.out.println("testAiChooseAction: failed");
        } else {
            System.out.println("testAiChooseAction: passed");
        }
    }
```

But it does not pass in test .The error is as follows :

```
testAiChooseAction 5: for seed 123 responses were expected to be [1037, 5819, 3144]  but found [3327, 3370, 3303]
testAiChooseAction: failed
```

How can I solve the error ? Please help me .

Comment: Please state the problem to solve _before_ any algorithm to do so. Don't write, and _never_ present uncommented code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is item 7:

> For example, if `Config.MIN_ACTION` is `1` and `Config.MAX_ACTION` is 3: If the action rankings are `{9,90,1}` the total is `100`. Since `actionRanking[0]` is `9`, then an action of picking up 1 should be chosen about 9/100 times. 2 should be chosen about 90/100 times and 1 should be chosen about 1/100 times.

Here's how that example should be implemented:

- First generate a random number between 0 and 99 inclusive (100 possible values).
- If the random number is less than 9, then return 1. Otherwise subtract 9 from the random number.
- If the adjusted random number is less than 90, then return 2. Otherwise subtract 90 from the adjusted random number.
- The only possibility left is that the adjusted random number is 0, which is less than 1, so return 3.

In general, the pseudocode for the AI function (after the special cases at the beginning) should look like this:

```
compute the 'sum' of the entries in the 'actionRanking' array
generate a random number `R` between '0' and 'sum-1' inclusive
for each entry in 'actionRanking'
   if the entry is greater than 'R'
      return 'Config.MIN_ACTION' + the index for that entry
   otherwise
      subtract the entry from 'R'
```

Comment: @SagorAhmed You're welcome, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

The result you are seeing is entirely to be expected.  The random number distribution is correct for the seed you're giving:

```
Random r = new Random();
r.setSeed(123);
int [] count = { 0, 0, 0 };
for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    count[r.nextInt(3)]++;
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(count));
```

Produces:

```
[3327, 3370, 3303]
```

The problem is that your code makes no attempt to adjust the weight of the random response.  Your should change this:

```
return Config.RNG.nextInt(Config.MAX_ACTION)+Config.MIN_ACTION;
```

and do the following:

At some stage before picking the index calculate the total weight of all the actions:

```
int totalWeight = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < actionRanking.length; i++) {
    totalWeight += actionRanking[i];
}
```

Then instead of just randomly picking an index, randomly pick a weight and determine which index corresponds to that weight:

```
int selection = Config.RNG.nextInt(totalWeight)+Config.MIN_ACTION;
int weight = Config.MIN_ACTION;

for(int i = 0; i < actionRanking.length - 1; i++) {
    weight += actionRanking[i];
    if (selection < weight) {
        return i + Config.MIN_ACTION;
    }
}
return Config.MAX_ACTION;
```

Testing shows this is much closer to your expected output, but it's not the same  (`[2959, 5998, 1043]`) - probably due to using nextInt(10) instead of nextInt(3).  You may want to change how you're calculating the expected results.

Comment: I have changed to this code . But this also fails in the test .

Comment: @SagorAhmed saying "This fails" does not help in the slightest.  Describe the behavior

Comment: testAiChooseAction 4: expected 3 rather than 1
testAiChooseAction 5: for seed 123 responses were expected to be [1037, 5819, 3144]  but found [6697, 3303, 0]

Comment: @SagorAhmed It was skipping the last action due to the `- 1`.  Remove that and try again.  But **beware**: how your expected results was calculated may differ from what this code produces.  Without knowing how it expects the weighting to occur you may easily get different results

Comment: @SagorAhmed took another look at this.  There was a typo in the calculation for `selection`.  Please change from `nextInt(Config.MIN_ACTION)` to `nextInt(totalWeight)`

Comment: testAiChooseAction 5: for seed 123 responses were expected to be [1037, 5819, 3144]  but found [2013, 5911, 2076]

Comment: @SagorAhmed Change `(selection <= weight)` to `(selection < weight)`.  Using a non zero based index is causing all sorts of grief.